# I get "No matching signature" error in my background.js

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, manifest

I get the error "Uncaught TypeError: Error in invocation of scripting.executeScript(scripting.ScriptInjection injection, optional function callback): No matching signature." in my console.
I have no idea what's wrong, someone please help me, I really appreciate it.

Here is the background.js code:

```
var Tabclicked = false;
disableBrowserAction();


function disableBrowserAction(tabId) {
    chrome.scripting.executeScript(tabId, { file: 'jquery.js' }, function() {
        chrome.scripting.executeScript(tabId, { file: 'CloseRuler.js' });
    });
}

function enableBrowserAction(tabId) {
    chrome.scripting.executeScript(tabId, { file: 'jquery.js' }, function() {
        chrome.scripting.executeScript(tabId, { files: 'Ruler.js' });
    });
}

function updateState() {
    if (Tabclicked == false) {
        Tabclicked = true;
        enableBrowserAction();
    } else {
        Tabclicked = false;
        disableBrowserAction();
    }
}

//chrome.pageAction.onClicked.addListener(updateState);

chrome.action.onClicked.addListener(function(tabId) {
    updateState(tabId);
    alert('File test alert');

});

alert('File test alert');
```

Here is my manifest:

```
{
    "name": "Physics Ruler",
    "description": "Position the ruler and measure the objects!",
    "version": "1.0",
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "permissions": [
        "activeTab",
        "scripting"
    ],
    "background": {
        "service_worker": "background.js",
        "type": "module"
    },
    "action": {
        "default_icon": "icon.png",
        "default_title": "Ruler",
        "name": "Physics Ruler"
    },
    "content_scripts": [{
        "js": ["jquery.js"],
        "matches": ["*://*/*"]
    }],
    "host_permissions": [
        "*://*/*"
    ]
}
```

Comment: The parameters of executeScript are incorrect, see the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/scripting/).

Comment: Yeah, I had try that by I don't know why when I write "const tabId = getTabId();" I get "getTabId is not defined". My extension was fully functional in version 2.

Comment: You don't need getTabId, you already have `tabId`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I have found the answer, and the documentation was kind of not help full, I have just tried different things until it worked.

We have to make this function with chrome tabs:

```
chrome.tabs.query({ currentWindow: true, active: true }, function(tabs) {
```

in that function then we can use "tabs[0].id" to get the id.

for example:

```
function enableBrowserAction(tabId) {
chrome.tabs.query({ currentWindow: true, active: true }, function(tabs) {
    chrome.scripting.executeScript({ target: { tabId: tabs[0].id }, files: ['jquery.js'] }, function() {
        chrome.scripting.executeScript({ target: { tabId: tabs[0].id }, files: ['Ruler.js'] });
    });
});
```

}

Comment: Remove chrome.tabs.query and replace tabs[0].id with `tabId`. Also you can specify two files in `files`.